# Environmental risk assessment based on sample number and concentrations of a toxic element

Tags: r, probability, weighted-sampling, risk

Happy New Year '14 everyone. I'm seeking a formal solution to a simple problem. I'm working with a database of a toxic element in different regions. I want to prioritize regions where immediate action should be taken based on my soil data (mean concentration of the toxic element in a region and the fraction of soil samples contaminated in that particular region). The idea is to put more weight on the fraction of soil samples contaminated. But I'm not sure if there's a nice way for quantifying the risk associated with such observations. For instance:

```
#region 01
#toxic element concentrations in 5 soil samples
#these observations have concentration unit (e.g. ppm, ppb, etc.)
t1<-c(0.05,0.05,0,0.05,0.05)
#mean of toxic element concentrations
m1<-mean(t1) 
> m1
[1] 0.04 
#fraction of contaminated soil samples in region 1 (we assume that,
#anything above 0.025 unit is dangerous for organisms
f1<-(length(which(t1 > 0.025))/length(t1)) ##no unit since fraction
> f1
[1] 0.8

#region 02
t2<-c(0.25, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.05)
m2<-mean(t2)
> m2
[1] 0.11
f2<-(length(which(t2 > 0.025))/length(t2))
> f2
[1] 0.6
```

The above observations in two different regions clearly demonstrate that there's no relation between fraction of soil samples contaminated and the mean concentrations; i.e. a region can have a large number of samples that are contaminated (or not contaminated) with a low (or high) mean concentration of the toxic element. A real STUPID way of prioritizing zones based on the provided data might be just adding fraction and mean:

```
#region 01
> m1+f1
[1] 0.84

#region 02
> m2+f2
[1] 0.71
```

This means that action should be taken in region 01 before region 02. But this solution is unacceptable in a global scale because I'm adding concentrations to the fraction which are unlike. If the concentrations were big numbers (say, 100  times the values shown above for another toxic element) and the safe threshold were 2.5 unit concentrations, the fraction remains same (0.8 and 0.6), but prioritized zones are flipped since region 2 ($11+0.6=11.6$) $>$ region 1 ($4+0.8=4.8$)! In other words, normalizing the toxic element concentrations to a fraction level is needed (if I want to put more weight on the fraction part), but I'm sure there's a statistically elegant way to deal with this. Is there any plausible relative probability distribution technique? Any package in R dealing with relevant problems?

Comment: This is a question about toxicology; it cannot be answered on statistical grounds. (*Far* more goes into evaluating environmental risk than looking at the distribution of concentrations in the exposure medium.) Some statistical insights can be provided, though. For instance, it is rather rare for soil samples to be obtained completely and independently at random. This calls into question the meaningfulness of the proportion "contaminated" (and even casts some doubt on the meaningfulness of their average). I suggest you rewrite your question to focus on issues where we can actually help.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can write a simpler version of my question. To remove your doubts, I might add that soil samples are collected uniformly (say 50-100 samples) everywhere. Therefore, there's no bias in comparing one region to another. A straight-forward solution can be: high proportion bad = high risk. But adding the weight of mean would be interesting in the scenario and that's what I'm looking for ... @whuber

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to optimize a weighting scheme to judge which region to prioritize targeting with corrective measures. You speak of risk and probability...of what? Do you have data on a dependent variable of interest? I assume this would be some outcome you're trying to predict and associate with your soil sample data, which seems to have contamination (binary?) and location information. If you have outcome data, you can conduct some useful inferential analyses to inform your weighting scheme; otherwise it seems like a matter contamination distribution and non-statistical factors.

Comment: You are absolutely correct: "It sounds like you're trying to optimize a weighting scheme to judge which region to prioritize targeting with corrective measures". I meant: what is the probability that a region with higher fraction of contaminated soil samples contain higher mean concentrations and vice-versa. Where the probability is high, the given weight of mean should be high, where the probability is low, the assigned weight of mean should be low ... @Nick